# Run query again once finished n times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working in a psql database and I want to leave something running overnight.

I have a function I am calling like this:

```
select func_name(21);
```

This function is transactionalised and once ran, inserts to the DB.

I then want to run the same function again (it has highwater marks, so it will know where to pick up from):

```
select func_name(21);
```

Lets say I want to run this 10 times - is this possible?

I had considered using something like `\gexec` but unsure how to make it work.

I can get the following:

```
select format('select func_name(%s)',id) from table where id = '21';
                   format                   
--------------------------------------------
 select func_name(21)
(1 row)
```

I know if I execute this using `\gexec` it will run once but is there a way I can get it to run ten times without using a loop within another function?

Comment: Schedule a job to run it periodically, say every hour.  That seems like this simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I was looking for:

```
                   format                   
--------------------------------------------
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
 select func_name(21)
```

From here, I could run a `\gexec` command